# Selecting a Unique Dropdown Element in a Web Scraping Program Using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a question regarding web scraping with Python using Selenium. I'm working on a project where I need to extract data from a specific website: **https://www.bps.go.id/en/exim**.

In my program, I've successfully implemented a feature to select either "import" or "export" from a dropdown menu. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to access elements within the "HS FULL" abbreviation section in the second part of the webpage.

I've attempted various methods, including XPath, class names, and text-based approaches, but I haven't been able to access the "HS FULL" elements. Despite my efforts, I'm still unable to select or interact with them.

If anyone has experience with web scraping and Selenium and can provide guidance or suggestions on how to access these elements, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  # Import NoSuchElementException
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


# Receive user input for the year and month
year = input("Enter the year (e.g., 2023): ")
month = input("Enter the month (e.g., 07): ")
# Receive user input for the sort option (1 for Import Weight, 2 for Export Weight)
user_input_im_ex = input("Enter '1' for Import Weight or '2' for Export Weight: ")

# Initialize a WebDriver (you need to download the appropriate driver for your browser)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')  # Replace with the path to your ChromeDriver executable

# Open the URL
url = 'https://www.bps.go.id/en/exim'
driver.get(url)

try:
    # Assuming user_input_im_ex is '1' for Import or '2' for Export
    if user_input_im_ex == '2':
        radio_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='1']")
        radio_button.click()
    elif user_input_im_ex == '1':
        radio_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='2']")
        radio_button.click()
    else:
        print("Invalid input for import/export option.")

    time.sleep(2)
    
    # Locate and click the input element to open the dropdown
    input_element = driver.find_element_by_id('react-select-filter-agregasi-input')
    input_element.click()

    # Send the Enter key to select the first option
    input_element.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(3)

    # # # Locate and select the element using its XPath
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ss"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]')
    element.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    
finally:
    # Close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a combination (Data, aggregation, ..) of values that return a valid table ? Whatever I set, I get *"Export or Import Data is not available. Please try another year, month, HS code, port, or country."*

Comment: @Timeless you can choose Import, By hs Code, HS FULL, 2023, 02022000 , ("port, country"<don't touch), "October"

Answer (score 0):

The website had **dynamic dropdown**, thats why you were not able to get the XPATH for **HS Full**.

To solve that, I used **event listener breakpoints**, by which when I click on the dropdrown, the scripts pauses and I was able to get the XPATH easily of the desired option.

**Steps to follow:**

In Developer tools open **Source** -> **Event Listener Breakpoints**

[image]

Then scroll down and enable **"click"** in Mouse

[image]

So now as you click the dropdown menu the page pauses and you can access the values of dropdown

[image]

Here is the code, and one more thing I've utilized **driver.find_element(by.XPATH, "....")** to locate elements:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException  # Import NoSuchElementException
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


# Receive user input for the year and month
year = input("Enter the year (e.g., 2023): ")
month = input("Enter the month (e.g., 07): ")
# Receive user input for the sort option (1 for Import Weight, 2 for Export Weight)
user_input_im_ex = input("Enter '1' for Import Weight or '2' for Export Weight: ")

# Initialize a WebDriver (you need to download the appropriate driver for your browser)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Webdriver\chromedriver.exe')  # Replace with the path to your ChromeDriver executable

# Open the URL
url = 'https://www.bps.go.id/en/exim'
driver.get(url)

try:
    # Assuming user_input_im_ex is '1' for Import or '2' for Export
    if user_input_im_ex == '2':
        radio_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='1']")
        radio_button.click()
    elif user_input_im_ex == '1':
        radio_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@value='2']")
        radio_button.click()
    else:
        print("Invalid input for import/export option.")

    time.sleep(2)
    
    # Locate and click the input element to open the dropdown
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "react-select-filter-agregasi-input").click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-select-filter-agregasi-option-0"]').click()

    time.sleep(3)

    # # # Locate and select the element using its XPath
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "react-select-filter-jenishs-input").click()
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-select-filter-jenishs-option-1"]').click()
    time.sleep(10)
    
finally:
    # Close the WebDriver
    driver.quit()
```